recv-keys from devcontainer's features/src/python/install.sh takes an exorbitant amount of time
I have a dev container with the ghcr.io/devcontainers/features/python:1 feature.  During install, the (*) Downloading GPG key... step takes a long time to execute.
The step executes a series of gpg -q --recv-keys over a set of ids.  There are 13 keys that need to be received.  Each gpg --recv-keys invocation takes 3 or 4 minutes, so the whole step takes 30 to 40 minutes.
Is there anything I can do to speed up the recv-keys step?
I can probably use ppa:deadsnakes/ppa to install a specific prebuilt version of python, but I'd like to understand the recv-keys problem.
